# XAMPP MySQL crashing

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hopefully someone ca help me out there. Every time I open XAMPP version 3.2.2, MySQL attempts to start but fails and I am greeted with the following message.....

Attempting to start MySQL app...

> 12:22:43 [mysql] Status change detected: running
>  12:22:44 [mysql]
>   Status change detected: stopped
>  12:22:44 [mysql] Error: MySQL
>   shutdown unexpectedly.
>  12:22:44 [mysql] This may be due to a
>   blocked port, missing dependencies,
>   12:22:44 [mysql] improper
>   privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>  12:22:44
>   [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   12:22:44 [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>  12:22:44
>   [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this
>  12:22:44 [mysql]
>   entire log window on the forums

Here is the error log for MySQL, I have searched online and have yet to find a solution

> 2017-02-28 12:16:46 1a28 InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note] InnoDB:
>   innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of
>   small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool
>   at least up to 20MB.
>
> 2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note] InnoDB: The
>   InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence()
>   are used for memory barrier
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696
>   [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>  2017-02-28
>   12:16:46 6696 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size =
>   16.0M
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696
>   [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
>   2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of
>   zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
>  2017-02-28
>   12:16:46 6696 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system
>   tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system
>   tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit
>   innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the
>   new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only
>   wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way.
>   But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your
>   precious data!
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB'
>   init function returned error.
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [ERROR]
>   Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>   2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>   2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine:
>   InnoDB
>  2017-02-28 12:16:46 6696 [ERROR] Aborting